# How do I format an NSString output?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, format, output

I have this Stock Market calculator I am working on that shows me in a label the total profit of the operation. The problem is that the output is `3984.00` and that's not the correct format we have here in Brazil which is `3.984,00`. So, how do I get the output `3984.00` to `3.984,00`?

Comment: Did you have a look at [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: I did and wrote a similar code like the one Skyte suggested. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like DrummerB said, check out [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Assuming your current locale is Brazilian, you could do something along those lines:

```
NSString *output = @"3984.00";

NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[output doubleValue]];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *groupingSeparator = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:groupingSeparator];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:YES];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];

NSString *desiredString = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

Edit: Forgot to add minimumFractionDigits.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it still shows me the same output: 3984.00

Comment: Maybe there is some confusion with the variable names. The format you want is found in the string named "desiredString", not in the string "output".

Comment: It was the missing minimumFractionDigits!!! Now it's working perfectly fine!!! Thnk you so very much Skyte!!!!